# use JDBC Thin driver to issue parallel queries into Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

Using Apache Ignite v2.6

As Apache Ignite version does not support JDBC connection pool against JDBC Thin Driver, what should be the approach to issue multiple parallel queries to Ignite? Document says that Ignite support 128 ResultSet/Cursor at a time. does this mean that 'A client will be able to shoot multiple queries in parallel, using a single connection'??

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you are referring to `maxOpenCursorsPerConnection` parameter. Its value doesn't specify the number of concurrent operations, it only limits the number of open cursors per connection.

A single JDBC connection cannot be used from multiple threads concurrently. You can use a connection pool instead. For example, take a look at [Hikari Connection Pool](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

Comment: yes, I confused on the 'maxOpenCursorsPerConnection'. But now you clarified it. will try on with HikariCP - hope this CP wont demand transaction support to avail the connection pool. As the test is finished, I will update it here.